# How to look for a specific child the Firebase real time database using cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to make a cloud function that will search for a specific child in my database.

This is my database structure:

```
places
   place_id_1
      users
         user1
            date: 1231233
         user2
            date: 3213424
   place_id_2
       users
          user3
             date: 123442
```

And what i'm trying to do is search to what node 'user1' is connected ('place_id_1' is this case).

It might have a lot of children under 'places' node, so it wont be a good idea to go over all of them (and it can take a lot of time..)

Is there a way to easily query and get all the nodes that are associated with a specific user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase only allow you to query at 1 level. You will need to create a reference table. Eg:

```
usersReference:   
  user1: 
   place_01
  user2: 
   place_02
```

Please have a look here: [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)